# nested layout in GetUIKit

Tags: getuikit

I want to show this layout using getuikit.com:

```
- option 1
- option 2. details: option 2a
```

I try as follows:
(it works if you put this snippet in a test.html file; in stackoveflow, the `select` appears in the next line for some reason)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.6/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.6/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
    <div class="uk-margin">
      <div class="uk-form-controls">
        <label><input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="aa"> option1</label>
        <br/>
        <div class="uk-form-horizontal">
          <label class="uk-form-label"><input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="aa"> option2. detail:</label>
          <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <select class="uk-select">
              <option>option 2a</option>
              <option>option 2b</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

however, "option 2" appears with a different small font. How to solve this?

Also, how to achieve this layout, with "details: ..." being indented under option 2?

```
- option 1
- option 2. 
  details: option 2a
```

ps: I've read the docs https://getuikit.com/docs/form and related, but I find it difficult to understand the construction.

Comment: second label has a class `.uk-form-label` while the first doesn't. to align it, you'll need to play with paddings and negative margins

Comment: yes, if i remove the -uk-form-label from the second label, then the `select` appears in a new line. it seems very esoteric to me.

Comment: you can't expect same behaviour of labels if you don't follow the same structure :)

Comment: ok, so how can I achieve the requested layout using GetUiKit?
(using a plain html table is so easy...)